# Bitmap decodeResource - out-of-memory crash on Samsung S5

Tags: android, bitmap, crash

I'm facing a crash every time with a Galaxy S5 when trying to show a background image.

This background is located in xxhdpi resource folder, the size is the same as the S5 screen (1080x1920) so I don't need to call "createScaledBitmap" for scaling it. The resolution of this image is JPG 96dpi.

And when calling decodeResource... crash!!! How is this possible? Is the only bitmap I'm loading in this "super-powerful" device.

Thanks!!!

Below my code (scale = 1 for S5):

```
public static Bitmap decodeBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId, float scale) {

    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, 
            (int)(options.outWidth*scale), 
            (int)(options.outHeight*scale));

    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    if (scale > 1) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId);
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, (int)(options.outWidth*scale), 
                (int)(options.outHeight*scale), true);
    }

    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line in your Manifest file in the application tag. It doesn't solve the problem just allows your app to have more memory:

```
 android:largeHeap="true"
```

**UPDATE:**

However using `largeHeap` is not a good solution. here is the google's doc about this.

> However, the ability to request a large heap is intended only for a
>   small set of apps that can justify the need to consume more RAM (such
>   as a large photo editing app). **Never request a large heap simply**
>   **because you've run out of memory and you need a quick fix**—you should
>   use it only when you know exactly where all your memory is being
>   allocated and why it must be retained. Yet, even when you're confident
>   your app can justify the large heap, you should avoid requesting it to
>   whatever extent possible. Using the extra memory will increasingly be
>   to the detriment of the overall user experience because garbage
>   collection will take longer and system performance may be slower when
>   task switching or performing other common operations.

And about loading bitmaps:

> When you load a bitmap, keep it in RAM only at the resolution you need
>   for the current device's screen, scaling it down if the original
>   bitmap is a higher resolution. Keep in mind that an increase in bitmap
>   resolution results in a corresponding (increase2) in memory needed,
>   because both the X and Y dimensions increase.

It's not bad to take a look at this page, it explains ways of managing memory:

[How Your App Should Manage Memory](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html#YourApp)

So I think my last answer is not a good solution and You might rethink your strategy in loading images. Hope this answer helps you ;)

Comment: Oh God! I had this line in the manifest tag, not in the application one. After moving it, it doesn't crash anymore.

Comment: :)) but it's better to reconsider about the way you use memory in your app.

Comment: Right. But it looks like I'm just decoding the image without scaling it (has the correct size), and without that largeHeap line it crashes... how is this possible? It's an S5!!

Comment: I started to see more and more answers like this one, but you should know that the use of largeHeap is not recommended in all cases, please use it very cautiously, it might slow other running application, and also impact your app's reactiveness, since the garbage collector with be solicited more often. For more information check this speech from google i/o https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk

Comment: This is a garbage solution. You're just raising the amount of time before your app crashes, and now it is even harder to reproduce.

Comment: @MartinKonecny Thanks for remembering me to update my old answer.

Comment: @Mood Thanks for remembering me to update my old answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public static Bitmap decodeBitmapFromResource(String pathName, int reqWidth, int  reqHeight) {
    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, options);
    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    // return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, options);
}



public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;
    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and
        // width
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
        // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will
        // guarantee
        // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
        // requested height and width.
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Comment: This is more or less what I'm doing. My problem was in the wrong position of the largeHeap tag :( Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

i too faced this problem many times...

try using this code..

```
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) throws IOException {
    Bitmap b = null;

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
            .getMetrics(metrics);

    // Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    o.inDither = false; // Disable Dithering mode
    o.inPurgeable = true; // Tell to gc that whether it needs free memory,
                            // the Bitmap can be cleared
    o.inInputShareable = true;

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o);
    fis.close();

    int scale = 1;
    if (o.outHeight > metrics.heightPixels
            || o.outWidth > metrics.widthPixels) {
        scale = (int) Math.pow(
                2,
                (int) Math.ceil(Math.log(metrics.heightPixels
                        / (double) Math.max(o.outHeight, o.outWidth))
                        / Math.log(0.5)));
    }

    // Decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o2);
    fis.close();

    return b;
}
```

and take care of few things like make every bitmap null after its use etc.