# OutOfMemoryError in Android on Galaxy note 1 (AOSP based ROM) when try to higher the resolution for a tiny little bit

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera, resolution

I've been dealing with images on Android and it's been quite a few days and I don't seem to be able to solve it.

In my app there is an "add photo" button. When the user clicks on it she can choose a photo from gallery or either take a new one with camera.

But in order to avoid getting OutOfMemoryError I have to lower the resolution so much that the picture sent to the server is almost nothing more than a thumbnail.

on this line when I change 200 to 250 it gives the mentioned error!
Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap2, 200, 200, true);

(The error happens on Android 4.2+, not on lower Androids. It works perfectly fine on Android 4.1 even with 400, 400)

Which part of my code is wrong?

Here is the code:

```
 public class CreatePropertyActivity5 extends ActionBarActivity {
protected static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
private static final int ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE_IMAGE = 100;
private static final int IMAGE_DESCRIPTION = 200;
LinearLayout ll; 
private List<File> cameraImageFiles;
private JSONRequestForCreatePropertyListing propertyListing;
ImageView imageView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_property_5);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    propertyListing = (JSONRequestForCreatePropertyListing) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("JSONRequestForCreatePropertyListing");
    CreatePropertListingAsync cplp = new CreatePropertListingAsync(this, propertyListing);
    cplp.execute();

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.create_property_activity5, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void onClickTakePicture(View v) throws IOException {
    // Camera.
    final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);     
    final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);


    cameraImageFiles = new ArrayList<File>();

    int i=0;
    for(ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
        final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
        final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(packageName);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.MEDIA_IGNORE_FILENAME, ".nomedia");

        //** below 4 lines put the uri of the camera taken picture to the EXTRA_OUTPUT 
        File cameraImageOutputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "myFileName");
        cameraImageFiles.add(cameraImageOutputFile);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(cameraImageFiles.get(i)));
        i++;

        cameraIntents.add(intent);
    }

    // Filesystem.
    final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

    // Chooser of filesystem options.
    final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "add new");

    // Add the camera options.
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE_IMAGE);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent)
{
    ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llCreatePropertyImages);

    switch(requestCode) { 

    // For sending photos to server. We come here from activity51
    case IMAGE_DESCRIPTION:
        String s = imageReturnedIntent.getStringExtra("key");
        //user entered description is in "key"
        imageView.setTag(s);
        Bitmap bitmap1 = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
        byte[] image=stream.toByteArray();
        String img_str = Base64.encodeToString(image, 0);

        //This part sends the picture to the server
        ArrayList<Photos> photos = new ArrayList<Photos>();
        photos.add(new Photos(new Ax(img_str)));

        int id = Integer.parseInt((String) ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_property_listing_ID)).getText());
        int editPass = Integer.parseInt((String) ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_property_listing_password)).getText());
        JSONRequestForAddPhoto jr = new JSONRequestForAddPhoto(id, editPass, photos);

        new AddPhotoAsync(this, jr).execute();
        break;

    //For choosing photos from gallery or taking one with camera
    case ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE_IMAGE:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            Uri uri = null;
            if(imageReturnedIntent == null){   //since we used EXTRA_OUTPUT for camera, so it will be null

                for(int i=0;i<cameraImageFiles.size();i++){
                    if(cameraImageFiles.get(i).exists()){
                        uri = Uri.fromFile(cameraImageFiles.get(i));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else {  // from gallery
                uri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            }

            if(uri != null){
                imageView = new ImageView(this);
                imageView.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 0);
                ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                try {

                    Bitmap bitmap2 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);
                    Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap2, 250, 250, true);
                    bitmap2.recycle();
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(scaled);
                    ll.addView(imageView);

                    //*** show activity51
                    Intent i= new Intent(this, CreatePropertyActivity51.class);
                    i.putExtra("photo", scaled);


                    startActivityForResult(i,IMAGE_DESCRIPTION);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 200x200 or even 400x400 is very small you are probably leaking memory. How many images do you keep on memory?

Comment: "The error happens on Android 4.2+, not on lower Androids. It works perfectly fine on Android 4.1 even with 400, 400" -- no, it will happen on any version of Android, when you do not have enough memory. Whether or not you have enough memory will be determined by a number of factors, including your process' heap limit and what you have done in that process prior to doing this work. There is no tight connection between your `OutOfMemoryError` and an Android version.

Comment: what you need is to optimize your code becuase outOfMemoryError usually accures when you load to many images in your app.

Comment: @rekire : This Activity is the only place I have images in. The onClickTakePicture() can be called many times. But I give error on the first call.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is not wrong but it can be optimized. but if you deal with some large images i suggest you take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27270469/2101822

Comment: Any suggestions for optimization? I recycle the bitmap. That is all I know for optimization here.

Comment: my boss is going to kill me. please take a look at this:
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap
it may help

Comment: :)) I have read that. What I don't know is how to get this resId since my imageView still has no image in it. Should I get the id from uri? can it be done? Cause I did not find any guide for that.

Answer (score 0):

I have a look at your code, but you are not doing the way mentioned in the developer site.
How to [load large bitmaps efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html):

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

Try it first!

Comment: My images are files saved on the device. What I have is their Uri, how can this resId in your code be achieved from Uri? I did not find anything that guides through that.

Comment: @Tina Have you read BitmapFactory class? You can always use BitmapFactory.decodeFile() instead of BitmapFactory.decodeResource() .